# Strange error during db connection

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, junit

Using JUnit to test a class that connects to Database Java print this error:

Error:Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Using the same class in a Main Class i have the same error.

Using the same class in a servlet, testing it from the browser, it works with no problems.

My database class to connect with DB (the error is on "ds.getConnection();"):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class Database {

    private static DataSource ds;

    static {
        try {
            Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

            ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/mua");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnessione() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }

}
```

This is the context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/mua"
        auth="Container"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="root"
        password="admin"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mua?useSSL=false"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: You may have register the driver (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)) which the Application container may do on its own...